# Show only posts from current user - firebase swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code that is getting every post and showing it all in a uitableviewcontroller. The code that is getting all of the posts from firebase is this:

```
viewDidLoad {
dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items")
    startObersvingDB()

}

func startObersvingDB() {
    dbRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newUpdates = [Sweet]()

        for update in snapshot.children {
            let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newUpdates.append(updateObject)

        }

        self.updates = newUpdates
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }) { (error: NSError) in
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

How can I modify that part to just get updates from a specific username?
My structure in firebase is like this:

```
feed-items {
    unique-user-id {
            post: "This is a post"
            byUsername: "MyUser"
    }
}
```

So what the code should be doing, is fetching the byUsername string - I just cannot figure out how to update my code to do that. Hope you guys can help me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

**Swift 3**

```
func startObersvingDB() {
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrdered(byChild: "byUsername").queryEqual(toValue: "MyUser").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    var newUpdates = [Sweet]()

    for update in snapshot.children {
        let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        newUpdates.append(updateObject)

       }

       self.updates = newUpdates
       self.tableView.reloadData()


        }) { (err) in
         print(err!.localisedDescription)      
      }
   }
```

**Swift 2**

```
func startObersvingDB() {
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedbyChild("byUsername").queryEqualtoValue("MyUser").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    var newUpdates = [Sweet]()

    for update in snapshot.children {
        let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        newUpdates.append(updateObject)

    }

    self.updates = newUpdates
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    }) { (error: NSError) in
       print(error.description)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you are fetching  every child of `feed-items` with `for update in snapshot.children {...}` You are never using the key `unique-user-id` to actually fetch a specific user ID. You have to either write a [database rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to allow a user to only view his own items OR you can use the following method (Swift 3 syntax):

1) Fetching user ID from FIRAuth:

```
 if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
   for profile in user.providerData {
      providerDataID = profile.providerID // save UID in variable e.g. providerDataID
      // fetch other FIRAuth stuff
   }
```

2) Get only feed-items with your UID:

```
ref.child("feed-items").child(providerDataID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in     
   if let userInfoDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
   // get values from the proper providerDataID ONLY
}
```

**Alternative:**
when doing the for-loop in your code check every child's UID if it is a match for your user but that would take up a some bandwith if you have a large DB

Comment: The unique user id is being "skipped" as I only look for snapshot.children - but someone already found my answer :-) Thanks for your time though!